# history command in shell doesn't work as expected (for me)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, zsh

I am trying to `set +o history` and `set -o history` to prevent credentials from being stored in shell history. But I keep getting the error

> set: no such option: history

But when I just type `history`, I can see the history just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: history -c also does not work

Comment: What shell are you running?

Comment: the mac terminal

Comment: The "terminal" it's only the thing that displays the output and that takes the input from your keyboard. The shell is running inside the terminal. So maybe you are running `zsh`, does `echo "$ZSH_VERSION"` output anything? zsh [differs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history) from bash.

Comment: @ssn : Please tag your question properly with the shell you are using (ksh, bash, zsh,....). You have tagged your question as 'shell', which would be "POSIX shell", but in that, you wouldn't have history, so your tagging is clearly wrong.

Comment: it is a bash shell

Comment: That's the error message you would get from `zsh`. In `bash`, a non-existent option would produce an error message like `bash: set: foobar: invalid option name`.

Answer (score 0):

You're running that command in zsh, the default shell for macOS now. zsh doesn't have the +o option to set.

Just enter `bash` to enter the bash shell, and your command will work.